# Search is giving 0 result because of space in word in Endeca

Tags: search, endeca

I have a product with title "703A155-52-10/144-N (B5)" when I search this I am getting no result but when I search with "703A155-52-10/144-N" I am able to retrieve the result. I have made Exact match on the search interface. Any pointer on how I can resolve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Endeca default search config only allow alpha-numeric characters to be searchable and remaining chars to replace by space.In your case endeca search term will be internally " 703A155 52 10 144 N".  This might be the reason why its not searchable. Make "-", "/" ,"(" and ")" chars searchable in Endeca pipeline config and run baseline. This would always gives you consistent results.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Ajay Agrawal

Comment: Alternatively, strip out the special characters when searching and replace with a space.